# Yii2. Why I need to upload file for two times to have an effect?

Tags: php, yii2, zip, unzip

I have an _form view for update and create. There is file input field, where only zip files are allowed. When zip is uploaded - it should be unzipped to a folder depending on a model name.

The problem is I have to upload it two times to have an effect, because first time doesn't give me unzipped folder.

This is the upload function in Model

```
public function upload()
{
    $this->uploadedFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'filepath');

    if (!empty($this->uploadedFile)) {
        $slug = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower(trim($this->name)));
        $htmlPathRel = '/html/' . $slug . '/';
        $htmlPathAbs = Yii::getAlias('@frontend') . '/web' . $htmlPathRel;

        // delete old files before extracting
        @array_map('unlink', glob($htmlPathAbs . '/*.*'));
        @rmdir($htmlPathAbs);

        // unpack new files
        $zip = new \ZipArchive;
        if ($zip->open(Yii::getAlias('@frontend') . '/web/uploads/' . $this->uploadedFile->name) === true) {
            $indexHtmlContent = $zip->getFromName('index.html');
            $order = new Order();
            $toSearch = array_filter($order->attributes(), function($value) {
                return strpos($value, 'name="billing_') !== false;
            }) + array('<form');

            if (!$indexHtmlContent) {
                $this->addError('filepath', 'index.html not found in ' . $this->uploadedFile->name);
                return false;
            }

            $notFound = [];

            foreach ($toSearch as $string) {
                if (strpos($indexHtmlContent, $string) === false) {
                    $notFound[] = $string;
                }
            }

            if (!empty($notFound)) {
                $this->addError('filepath', 'index.html doesn\'t contain required data: ' . implode(', ', $notFound));
                return false;
            }
            if (!is_dir($htmlPathAbs)) {
                mkdir($htmlPathAbs);
            }
            $zip->extractTo($htmlPathAbs);
            $zip->close();
        }

        $this->filepath = $htmlPathRel . 'index.html';

        $this->save();

        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@frontend') . '/web/uploads/' . $this->uploadedFile->baseName . '.' . $this->uploadedFile->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is controller create and update actions:

```
/**
 * Creates a new Html model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Html();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Product::updateRoutes();
            $model->upload();
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Updates an existing Html model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param string $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $filepath = $model->filepath;
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Product::updateRoutes();
            if (!$model->upload()) {
                $model->filepath = $filepath;
            }
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

PS: any code refactoring ideas are welcome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving the file to `@frontend/web/uploads` after unzipping the file from this folder so it works only when the file is there - second time.